# Difference between RSS and Web API?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, web-services, rss

> I have searched a lot on web to find a satisfactory answer but I did't get an answer.
>
> Some says RSS is static xml while in web API we make a proper format of request and get a proper format of response

Kindly help me on this
thanks,

Comment: RSS (Rich Site Summary) is a format for delivering regularly changing web content. It is widely used by News Portals, web logs where the content changes very often. This RSS feed follows a specific format for data exchange. User won't be sending any input parameters to the server 

Web API can do something more that this, where user will be sending a Request to the server in a predfined format and get the response from  server.In web API data contract can be anything XML ,JSON etc. Here the response format can be detemined by the API owner.

Comment: but why we use RSS if we can achieve all this using get/post.

Comment: RSS is interroperable. If you fetch an RSS feed from site A or site B, it's in the same format. I have yet to see interroperble APIs where, even for the same type of content, the format is the same.

Answer (score 10):

The reason RESTful APIs are so inconsistent across different services is because REST is not a standard, it's not a protocol.  It's an architectural style.  Some things to take into consideration for your API would be; what HTTP verbs to support, what URI structure to follow, how to consistently return error messages, how to handle partial selection, versioning, authentication, pagination, and so on and so forth..  There is no specific right way of doing it (it's debated often), but there are many ways that are not so great!

RSS stands for Really Simple Syndication, which is essentially a format for delivering regularly changing web content. RSS feeds allow a user to subscribe to their favorite news sources, blogs, websites, and other digital properties, and then receive the latest content from all those different areas or sites in one place, without having to repeatedly visit each individual site.

Answer (score 4):

Your question sounds like "What difference is between Ford Focus and a taxi service?" Ford Focus *can* be one of the cars in a taxi service. But nothing more.

RSS is a standard, which describes specific format of news feed. You can have a standalone locally stored RSS-formatted file, remote stored RSS-file somewhere on a server, or you can have a web-service which constructs RSS-formatted file on the fly. It will be RSS in all three cases because RSS is something that describes *internal structure* of a file.

Web Service is, basically, *an application* which runs somewhere on a server, accepts requests, processes it according to the application's internal logic, and then provides answers. Web service can take any kind of requests and provide any kind on responses, including RSS-formatted ones.
Hope that makes things a bit clearer for you.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply but 
I have a question why we use RSS if we can achieve all this using get/post request

Comment: RSS is a *content* format, and get/post is a *way of delivery*. You can receive RSS-formatted content via GET request. Your question, again, sounds like "Why do we use .xls if we can use email attachments?" While email attachment is just *a way of delivery* for xls-file.

Comment: sorry for this rubbish question as I could not understand the difference now I accpeted thanks

Answer (score 1):

We will be using RSS as broadcasting channel, who ever wants to know what's happning in my Company can follow my company website's RSS feed.